# Programmatically click link Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

So I am trying to Click a link programmatically. Its a Play button on a video player and due to a poor combo of Ad serves and player, I can't just autoplay the video, I need to programmatically click it.

HTML for button

```
<div class="vjs-big-play-button" role="button" aria-live="polite" tabindex="0" aria-label="play video"><span aria-hidden="true"></span></div>
```

On desktop this is no issue, it works flawless

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".vjs-big-play-button").trigger('click');
});
```

On mobile though, nothing happens. (Side note, I have cursor set to pointer)

I have tried

```
$(".vjs-big-play-button").trigger('touchstart');
```

-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.vjs-big-play-button').on('click touchstart',function() {
    $(this).trigger('click');
  });
});
```

-

```
$(document).on({ 'touchstart' : function(){ 
  $(".vjs-big-play-button").trigger('click');
 }});
```